# WPF EditingCommands Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

The Situation:

I have some Editing commands in WPF window, and a close command (Application.CloseCommand) and have some bindings like this

**View:**

```
 <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                        Executed="CloseCommandBinding_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold"
                        Executed="EditingCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
 </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"></KeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
.. *Some panel and grid stuff and more things* ..
<RichTextBox Name="RTBPopup">
       <RichTextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"></KeyBinding>
       </RichTextBox.InputBindings>
</RichTextBox>
.. *Some panel and grid stuff and more things* ..
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggleBold" CommandManager.Executed="EditingCommand_Executed" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RTBPopup}">B</ToggleButton>
```

Now:

If I press escape in RTBPopup (Richtextbox) the command gets executed and the debugger hits the breakpoint set on `CloseCommandBinding_Executed` method

***but***

when I click on toggle button for bold or press control + B, the EditingCommand_Executed is not getting hit by debugger (not getting executed)

What else I have tried:

```
 <ToggleButton.CommandBindings>
      <CommandBinding Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" Executed="EditingCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
 </ToggleButton.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 2):

Handle the `PreviewExecuted` event:

```
<CommandBinding Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" 
                PreviewExecuted="CommandBinding_PreviewExecuted" />
```

The command is handled by the `RichTextBox` so it never bubbles up to your parent `Window`.

You could also try to use the `CommandManager` to hook up the event handler programmatically:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(RTBPopup, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(OnExecuted));
    }

    private void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Command == EditingCommands.ToggleBold)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("fired!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck ... The command is being executed but not breakpoint hit

Comment: See my edit. You could use the CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler method.

Comment: I tried that earlier for CommandExecuted, tested for PreviewExecuted .... Still no luck .... Another part of the problem is, I can still manage the Command on button, But I really want to handle the shortcut command (Ctrl + B), that user will use for sure

Comment: Are you saying that my sample code doesn't work? It does for me so please provide a *full* compilable sample of your issue.

Comment: I can attest that the sample code works.